# JFace TreeViewer flickering

Tags: java, eclipse, treeview, jface

I'm trying to update the input of JFace TreeViwer periodically using `setInput()` method. Also I use the

```
viewer.setExpandedElements(expandedElements);
viewer.setExpandedTreePaths(expandedTreePaths);
```

methods to save the state of the tree. But after each `setInput()` call the TreeViewer flickers. How can avoid from flickering ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the actual input changing? If not you can call `refresh()` instead... or ideally use TreeViewers add/remove/update methods to avoid having to rebuild the entire tree.

You could try calling `viewer.getTree().setRedraw(false)` before the calls to `setExpand`, and then `viewer.getTree().setRedraw(true)` after.